# How to trust a Root CA for VPN use on Android 11

Tags: vpn, android-11

I want to connect my Android 11 phone to a VPN. The VPN is authenticated by a certificate signed by my own Certificate Authority (very typical).

I load the Root CA on the Android device by importing from local storage and the Root CA shows perfectly fine in the UI.

However, when connecting to VPN, the logs I get show that it can't validate the VPN server because it's certificate can't be validated because the Root CA isn't trusted.

Yet, the Android settings UI shows it is trusted.

The exact log message I get with logcat is:

```
received end entity cert "CN=xxxxxxxx"
received issuer cert "C=US,ST=......... CN=Intermediate CA"
received issuer cert "C=US,ST=......... CN=Root CA"
   using certificate "CN=xxxxxxxx"
   using trusted intermediate ca certificate "C=US..... CN=Intermediate CA"
checking certificate status of "CN=xxxxxxxx"
   using untrusted intermediate certificate "C=US..... CN=Root CA"
checking certificate status of "C=US.... Intermediate CA"
   self-signed certificate "C=US.... CN=Root CA" is not trusted
```

That does not make any sense as both the Root CA and Intermediate CA are loaded in the user's trusted CA store.

The certificates were created with OpenSSL, have the CA=True flag, etc.

Anyone knows how to get that to work?

Comment: How long is the validity time of the VPN cert? In Chrome Google started to accept only certificates with a validity period of less than 2 years (or less I am not sure). May be Android now behaves similar for VPN certs?

Comment: Had this thought also. CA should be able to be much longer than 1-2 year... what Chrome does not accept is server certificate being longer. I verified and even with a 1 year certificate identifying the VPN endpoint, it complains the CA is not trusted.

Comment: Why is the root CA certificate sent to the client?

Comment: @ecdsa That's how PKI works. TLS works the same. When you go to an HTTPS web site, the web site sends you it's certificate which is signed by a CA and your browser validates the certificate because you have the CA already trusted in your browser (done by Google, Mozilla, Microsoft). The CA certificates must be on the client station.

Comment: That's exactly why I asked why the **root** CA certificate is sent. It makes no sense as the client _has_ to trust that beforehand (you say so yourself). It can't establish trust in a self-signed root certificate received from a random host it connects to. So why does the server send it? Also, that the client doesn't find a trusted version of that certificate (it only finds the received one) could indicate that there is something wrong with your PKI (e.g. the root CA you installed on the client not being the one that issued the received intermediate CA certificate).